# apt-get update stuck at 0% , not working with ipv4

Tags: networking, internet, update-manager, proxy

When I do update it gets stuck

```
sudo apt-get update

Ign:1 cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20180228) xenial InRelease
Hit:2 cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20180228) xenial Release
0% [Connecting to de.archive.ubuntu.com (141.30.62.24)] [Connecting to archive.canonica
```

and then:

```
host de.archive.ubuntu.com

de.archive.ubuntu.com is an alias for ubuntu.mirror.tudos.de.
ubuntu.mirror.tudos.de has address 141.30.62.21
ubuntu.mirror.tudos.de has address 141.30.62.22
ubuntu.mirror.tudos.de has address 141.30.62.23
ubuntu.mirror.tudos.de has address 141.30.62.24
```

I'm not able to ping de.archive.ubuntu.com :

```
ping de.archive.ubuntu.com

PING ubuntu.mirror.tudos.de (141.30.62.26) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- ubuntu.mirror.tudos.de ping statistics ---
9 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 8090ms
```

but I can get on the website with browser.
How can I use apt-get update ?

Comment: Does `apt clean; apt autoclean; apt update` help?

Comment: @NerdOfLinux no, I have tried. But it does not work.

Comment: Does your computer support IPv6?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add in ipv4 dns settings adresses: 8.8.4.4,8.8.8.8 but it looks like these repos are temporarily turned off